# How to see if running under service fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I sometimes run projects locally out of visual studio is there a better way to detect if I'm hosted by SF rather than the exception. I can see possibly the path or entry assembly but there must be a better way.

```
try
{
    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("FisConfigUIType",
        context = > new WebHost < Startup > (context, loggerFactory, "ServiceEndpoint", Startup.serviceName)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
catch (FabricException sfEx)
{
    RunLocal(args, loggerFactory);
}
```

Comment: If you share with us why do u need to know, I might help us come up with a better solution.

Comment: We run the solutions locally in VS with F5 for debug instead of deploying to a cluster which take to long .

Comment: I wonder if the new 2.2 SDK will solve your problem. It introduced a great features: Local debugging with 1-Node cluster. You can check the release notes for more info https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/09/13/release-of-service-fabric-sdk-2-2-207-and-runtime-5-2-207/

Comment: It helps but packaging even a small core app is well over 100 Meg so id still like some sort of ISSFHosted without a handled exception

Comment: Great question, [opened a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/656) hoping they will improve this.

Answer (score 22):

Check [Service Fabric Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration#service-fabric-environment-variables):

```cs
var sfAppName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Fabric_ApplicationName");
var isSf = sfAppName != null;
```

Source: from @mkosieradzki [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/656#issuecomment-345356507)

Comment: This should be upvoted and it also has the benefit of having no dependency in the entry lib.

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

This is what i have come up with but something without an exception would be better (and note some projects use Core)

```cs
static bool IsSFHosted()
{
    try
    {
        FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext();
        return true;
    }
    catch (FabricException sfEx) when (sfEx.HResult == -2147017661 || sfEx.HResult == -2147017536 || sfEx.InnerException?.HResult == -2147017536)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

eg.

```cs
var isSFHosted = IsSFHosted();
var servicesPreRegister = builder.GetPreRegisterServicesForStore(node: node, security: false);

if (isSFHosted)
{
    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("DeliveriesWriteType",
        context => new WebAPI(context, loggerFactory, servicesPreRegister)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
else
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    // run with local web listener with out SF
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly this intended to work?

Comment: If ( IsSFHosted == false) { starviatweblistener( ..)  }     // obviously does not work for stateful services

Comment: GetNodeContext does not throw an exception on local debug cluster and on on-premises cluster. Still, I don't understand how this intended to work. I had to change the code to get it working.
var node = FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext();
return node.IPAddressOrFQDN != "localhost";

Comment: Added above to a console application to try it. I get a BadImageFormatException which I can't even catch with a try-catch block: System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Fabric, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Comment: you still need to compile for 64bit for the SF code

Comment: @cassandrad the main use for us is we re-use the service code when not hosted in SF but the best use is you can debug locally with deploying to the local cluster.